# Set two .col side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

whenever I change the display size, the 2 col jump under each other. How do I make them stay next to each other

```
<div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center header-phone">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x"  ></i>
    <div class="col text-center " ><h5>Rufen Sie uns an</h5><h5>+49 7433 2106989</h5></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center  header-mail" >
  <h5 class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center text-center" >Kontakt</h5>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: you need to use rest of bootstrap grid class to support smaller viewport ex: col-sm, col-xs

Comment: @DCR Yes, those are bootstrap classes

Answer (score 0):

palce two `div` element in a container and set `display:flex;` for container.

```css
.container-div{
  display: flex;
}
.container-div div{
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div">
<div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center header-phone">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x"  ></i>
    <div class="col text-center " ><h5>Rufen Sie uns an</h5><h5>+49 7433 2106989</h5></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center  header-mail" >
  <h5 class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center text-center" >Kontakt</h5>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: #M.R MRF Thank you very much. It works very well